# What's a good 'empty state' for a Delayed Buses display?

Tags: status, displays, empty

I am designing a screen display wireframe that will show late buses on the screen. But I am wondering if the buses are still en-route, what would be good to show in the screen as there is no information to display yet?

**Screen Display if Got Delayed Buses:**

[image]

**Screen Display if Buses are still Enroute:**
[image]

Comment: is there any bus timing available? What happens when I click on delayed/arrived bus? Will user see any information available?

Comment: Could you give more context? Why are a user is looking for bus timing? He must be willing to go somewhere. "Delayed" doesn't say much. 2 delayed buses are not equal given the "original timing" they'd have. A delayed bus that should originally arrives/departs in 5 minutes is not the same that the one in 15min

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there is a legitimate reason for having timetables separated for buses that are running on time and those that are delayed (I would argue that having all buses on 1 timetable and showing them in order of expected arrival time with delayed buses highlighted would make more sense) if there are no delayed buses, perhaps show a message that says 'All buses currently running on time'. If the data is loading maybe show a message like 'Fetching information of delayed buses'.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the empty state, you can show the expected time it can arrive at stop. Or if it is delayed then by what time and how much time will it cost more.
2. What are the alternatives? Like if bus X goes from A to B and is delayed then you can show the possible alternatives that a user can consider to go to B or the stops between.